# How can I accomplish this css grid

Tags: angularjs, css

I am trying to accomplish this grid:

[image]

In a way that, if possible, not using columns (I know it is easy using columns or bootstrap) but, what I pretend is to do an ng-repeat with angular and this way I don't have to worry about the order of the news, so I just take the data from a list and let `CSS` do the job with alignment. Thought the best way should be using **nth-child**. News order will be from newer to last, 1-7 as shown in the image.

So far this is what I have [tried](http://plnkr.co/edit/ThzMPy1lCSkFpLUjoXk8).

```css
.main-feed .feed-item {
  margin: 1em 1%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #008edb;
  position: relative;
}

.main-feed .feed-item:nth-child(1) {
  width: 48%;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
}

.main-feed .feed-item:nth-child(2) {
  width: 48%;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}

.main-feed .feed-item:nth-child(3) {
  width: 23%;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

.main-feed .feed-item:nth-child(4) {
  width: 23%;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
}

.main-feed .feed-item:nth-child(5) {
  width: 23%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.main-feed .feed-item:nth-child(6) {
  width: 23%;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
}

.main-feed .feed-item:nth-child(7) {
  width: 48%;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-feed">


  <div class="wrapper">
    <!--This is what i want to ng-repeat-->
    <article class="feed-item">
      <h1>1</h1>
    </article>
    <article class="feed-item">
      <h1>2</h1>
    </article>
    <article class="feed-item">
      <h1>3</h1>
    </article>
    <article class="feed-item">
      <h1>4</h1>
    </article>
    <article class="feed-item">
      <h1>5</h1>
    </article>
    <article class="feed-item">
      <h1>6</h1>
    </article>
    <article class="feed-item">
      <h1>7</h1>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

How can I make 5,6,7 to align just below 2?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This would require a javascript solution if you have variable heights.  It is quite compicated to code, but this has been done pretty well with https://masonry.desandro.com/. No need to re-invent the wheel :)

Comment: Please check this css feature, which is what you want to do. (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can produce the layout you describe in your question using **CSS Grid Layout**. There are several ways to produce the layout via CSS grids, but one of the most straightforward approaches would be to use `display: grid` and `grid-template-areas`.

**Working Example:**

```css
.main-feed {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 90px 90px 90px 90px;
grid-template-rows: auto;
grid-column-gap: 12px;
grid-row-gap: 12px;
grid-template-areas: 
    "article-1 article-1 article-2 article-2"
    "article-1 article-1 article-2 article-2"
    "article-1 article-1 article-2 article-2"
    "article-1 article-1 article-5 article-6"
    "article-3 article-4 article-5 article-6"
    "article-3 article-4 .         article-6"
    "article-3 article-4 article-7 article-7"
    "article-3 .         article-7 article-7"
    ".         .         article-7 article-7";
}

.feed-item {
min-height: 120px;
background-color: #008edb;
}

.feed-item h2 {
margin: 18px;
}

.main-feed article:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: article-1;
}

.main-feed article:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: article-2;
}

.main-feed article:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: article-3;
}

.main-feed article:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-area: article-4;
}

.main-feed article:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-area: article-5;
}

.main-feed article:nth-of-type(6) {
  grid-area: article-6;
}

.main-feed article:nth-of-type(7) {
  grid-area: article-7;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-feed">

<article class="feed-item">
<h2>1</h2>
</article>

<article class="feed-item">
<h2>2</h2>
</article>

<article class="feed-item">
<h2>3</h2>
</article>

<article class="feed-item">
<h2>4</h2>
</article>

<article class="feed-item">
<h2>5</h2>
</article>

<article class="feed-item">
<h2>6</h2>
</article>

<article class="feed-item">
<h2>7</h2>
</article>

</section>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed plus example. I will have to check out what CSS grid offers. Thanks for sharing your solution